# How does the calendar on windows phone work?

Tags: settings, notifications

I am unable to understand or able to make use of calendars. Right now I have a Facebook account and a windows live account setup on my phone. Contact have been filtered to just show the live contact and hide Facebook ones.

In the calendars app I have enabled both the Facebook and live, but I never get a reminder or see a birthday from either Facebook or live account. Even if I scroll through the year, I can't see anything.

Do we get a reminder or in any way can see the birthdays for today and coming days. All i can see right now are the invites for coming and gone by events. In short i have no way of knowing whose birthday is when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Actually there was no problem with settings on the phone. The issue was enabling the birthday calendars from the live sever.

To do so, I logged into the  and enabled the calendars for birthday and holidays. Now things are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the settings there are options to select the different calendars and some other options regarding them.

Comment: I have seen all those but couldn't get this done.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the options available?